# Calculating angular velocity of fairground ride

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

> A fairground ride has a circular track with a radius of $10 \textrm{ m}$. If a carriage moves at $7\textrm{ ms}^{-1}$, what is its angular velocity ?

Is the following correct ?

$$\text{radius} = 10 \text{ m}\\
\text{velocity} = 7 \text{ ms$^{-1}$}$$
$$\therefore v = \omega r \\
\therefore \omega = \frac{v}{r} \\
\therefore \frac{7\text{ ms$^{-1}$}}{10\text{ m}} \\
\therefore \omega = 0.7 \text{ ms$^{-1}$}$$

Comment: Yes it is right

Comment: $\omega$ is not in $m.s^{-1}$.

Comment: What i do not understand though is that my teacher said the equation for angular velocity is w = (2 x Pi) / T. So why is the equation I used different ? ( I got it from Google).

Comment: $\omega=\frac{v}{r}=\frac{2\pi r}{Tr}=\frac{2\pi}{T}$

Comment: Angular velocity is the number of radians a rotating thing covers in a time period. So $2\pi/T$ is just saying "it takes $T$ seconds to cover $2\pi$ radians, hence its angular velocity is $2\pi/T$. By comparison, here you know that the circumference is moving at $7 m/s$, so what you're doing is working out how many radians are covered by $7 m$ at the circumference.

Comment: @Dan Notice the changes I made to your question.  (1) I chose better tags. (2) I put the exercise in block quotes.  (3) I used [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the equations, numbers, and units to make it more readable.  Try to implement these in your future questions so someone else doesn't have to.

Comment: Also I left in all the "therefore"'s (the $\therefore$'s) from your work, but really you don't need that at *every* line.  Just a friendly note on readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything except the units are correct. Think of the units as a separate algebraic equation, so that the $m$ cancels, leaving you with just $s^{-1}$ as your units (which are also the units for $\frac{2 \pi}{T}$). The equation  $\omega = \frac {2 \pi}{T} $ is completely equivalent to $\omega = \frac{v}{r}$. This is intuitive if you consider: $$\frac {v}{r} = \frac{2 \pi}{T} $$
$$vT = 2 \pi r $$
This says that in one full period, the distance traveled will be the circumference of a circle with radius $r $, which is consistent with the idea of period.